# Can't figure out how to get basic ruby 'encryptor' to work

Tags: ruby

Basically want to make 'abc' into 'bcd'. I was thinking if I add the letter the follows the first to the end of the phrase and dropped the original first letter, eventually I'd get the final solution. Got kinda stuck and was hoping someone could shed some light on it for me. Thanks

```
def encrypt(str)
  index = 0
  encrypted_str = ""
  duration = str.length
  until index == str.length
    encrypted_str = str + str[0].next
    encrypted_str = encrypted_str + encrypted_str.delete(str[index])
    index += 1 
  end
  puts encrypted_str
end

#puts "What would you like to encrypt?"
message = "abc"
puts encrypt(message)
```

Comment: "Can't figure out how to get to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of the intended behavior including any and all rules, exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases; and also provide example inputs and desired outputs demonstrating both normal cases and the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Nah fall back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, which uses more power of stdlib :)

```
def original
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
end
def replacement 
  "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" 
end

def encrypt(str)
  str.tr(original, replacement)
end

def decrypt(str)
  str.tr(replacement, original)
end


encrypt('abc') # => "bcd"
decrypt('bcd') # => "abc"
```

Quite flexible too (compared to `succ`-based approach). You can change `replacement` alphabet to define *arbitrary* transformation rules.

Comment: Best way so far, imo. `def original; [*'a'..'z'].join; end; def replacement; original[1..-1] << original[0]; end` are perhaps a wee bit safer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code analysis..
Since you already initializing `encrypted_str` with empty string, there's no need to append it to original string and then `slice` it again..that's where it is getting messed up..just do the following..

```
until index == duration #you are not using duration too if assigned it to a variable
  encrypted_str += str[index].next[0]
  index += 1 
end
```

Taking the index 0 for next string because `'z'.next` returns `aa`

An alternative one liner approach would be..

```
message.each_char.map { |s| s.next[0] }.join
```

- [`chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-chars) will split the message into individual characters
- [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map) collects the manipulated characters into an array
- [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-join) will join individual characters from mapped array to a string again

---

**To Decrypt**

```
encrypted_str.each_char.map { |s| s.eql?('a') ? 'z' : (s.ord-1).chr }.join
```

Comment: Well, it seems we have to wait for something better.

Comment: Yes..there might be better solutions..but atleast the downvoter should say why this is bad..

Comment: I have a tiny suggestion: use `each_char` (which returns an enumerator) rather than `chars` (which produces an unneeded intermediate array) whenever it is followed, as here, by an enumerable. Reserve `chars` mainly for `Array` instance methods.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. I also wanted to make a decrypt option to essentially do the opposite. How would that look like with the first method above? Thanks! @Md.FarhanMemon

Answer (score 2):

```
ENCRYPT = [*'a'..'z'].zip([*'b'..'z', 'a']).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c",..., "y"=>"z", "z"=>"a"}
DECRYPT = ENCRYPT.invert
  #=> {"b"=>"a", "c"=>"b",..., "z"=>"y", "a"=>"z"}

def encrypt(str)
  crypt(str, ENCRYPT)
end

def decrypt(str)
  crypt(str, DECRYPT)
end

def crypt(str, mapping)
  str.gsub(/./, mapping)
end

encrypt('abc')   #=> "bcd"
decrypt('bcd')   #=> "abc"

encrypt('amnrz') #=> "bnosa"
decrypt('bnosa') #=> "amnrz"
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a hash as an argument. See also [Hash#invert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert).